# Deploying and giving access to SSIS package (.DTSX)

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis, ssis-2012, ssis-2008

I am new to SSIS, I have created a package for inserting data from Excel to SQL table. And I am able to do that. But now am struck at one point, when I am giving that package to someone, he is not able to execute it. Execute Package Utility is in disable mode. Only close button is active.

Can someone please help me with this? How can I enable other users to execute the package and change confirmation if required?

Comment: Why not just give him the project?

Comment: Actually there are multiple users who will use this. For running from the project they need SSIS services in there systems which is not provided to them